# negative value is being printed by c compiler

Tags: c

Problem : negative value is being printed

```
            #include<stdio.h>
//structure defination
            struct complex
            {
                float r;
                float i;
            };
            typedef struct complex CMPLX;
// addition is done here
            CMPLX add(CMPLX a,CMPLX b)
            {
                CMPLX c;       //structure of c
                c.r = a.r+b.r;
                c.i=a.i+b.i;
                return c;

            }
//function to read
            CMPLX read(CMPLX r)
            {

                printf("enter real part of complex number ");
                scanf("%f",&r.r);
                printf("\n");
                printf("enter imaganary part of complex number ");
                scanf("%f",&r.i);
                    printf("\n");
                return r;
            }
//function to write
            void write(CMPLX w)
            {
                printf("real part= %f   and imaginary part is  %f",w.r,w.i);
                    printf("\n");

            }
            void main()
            {
                CMPLX a;
                CMPLX b;
                CMPLX c;
                printf("\n");
                printf("enter first complex number");
                printf("\n");
                read(a);
                printf("complex numbes is");
                printf("\n");
                write(a);
                printf("\n");
                printf("enter second complex number");
                printf("\n");
                read(b);
                printf("complex numbes is");
                write(b);
                printf("\n");
                c=add(a,b);
                printf("added complex number");
                printf("\n");
                write(c);
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please go through the FAQ before posting questions here.Do some background reserch of similair post.Question redability ,Better formatting etc.

Comment: Please stop bombarding this post with downvotes. OP is new at stack so please guide OP. @OP please read [FAQ] for better question quality and enjoy this great forum.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore We are not downvoting the OP. We are downvoting the question. It is nothing personal. It does not make the question better than it comes from someone who is new. The question does not show research effort, is unclear and not useful. If you disagree with this approach, take it up with the people who labelled the buttons, or find another website that you like more.

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes everyone is downvoting question, but the OP is new to this site and we as an experienced SO member should encourage and give guidance  to new members instead of just giving downvote and moving to next question. Only Lithu T.V has done that. And it's my personal responsibility to tell everyone how to use this community who is new to site.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore “your personal responsibility”? Dude, you just provided a link to an FAQ. Actually I was showing someone how to ask his first question today, and the FAQ is displayed to you and must be acknowledged before you are allowed to ask your first question. So you provided a link to a page that the OP has already seen and acknowledged.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The FAQ contains Dos and Don'ts and if OP had read it then the quality of the question would have been better. What I wanted a reason for downvote so that user can improve his post. He actually doesn't know what's wrong so it's our responsibility to tell him so. What I found wrong in his question was the formatting and I corrected it. One who has downvoted should also have commented the reason for downvote as the OP is new.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Please read this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/159850

Answer (score 2):

`read(a);` should be `a = read();` .

You do not use the returned value (and parameters pass by value in C), so the values you enter in `read()` do not get assigned to `main` 's `a` . The values you see will be based on whatever garbage was in memory where `a` is being stored.

Further, the parameter to `read` has no effect since you just treat it like a local variable. Instead just declare a local variable `r` inside `read`, and return that.

Also it would be good to call your functions something other than `read` and `write` if you are on a POSIX system as they may clash with POSIX functions of those names.

Another good idea would be to check whether `scanf` succeeded or failed (it returns `1` on success in your case). If you do not do this, then typing in letters will cause your program to malfunctions.

Answer (score 0):

After addition, the value is going beyond float's limit. Try using double instead of float.

Answer (score 0):

Your `read()` function returns a value, but you ignore what it returns.  You also pass it an argument by value which is uninitialized.  You need to drop the argument, and use the return value:

```
CMPLX read(void) { CMPLX r; …other code as before… }

a = read();
```

Etc.

You also have spelling mistakes and inconsistencies galore in the code.  Consistency is extremely important in programming; it is good if you spell well too, but consistency is far more important.

You should check that `scanf()` worked each time you use it.

Also, unless you are programming on Windows, using `void main()` is not legitimate.  The return type of `main()` is `int` unless your implementation gives you permission to use a different type.